# Migrate aura:waiting and aura:doneWaiting to LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, migration

Link from SF for documentations about Aura waiting and doneWaiting.

[Aura waiting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:waiting/documentation)

[Aura doneWaiting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:doneWaiting/documentation)

I also check the link of migration from Aura to LWC.
[Aura migration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.migrate_introduction)

However, I could not find the equivalent expressions for these in LWC?
Please help to advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't an "equivalent" to speak of. Just increment a counter by one for each server-side call start, and decrement by one for each return.

```
  @track spinCount = 0;
  callServer(method, params, cb, eb) {
    this.spinCount++;
    setTimeout(function() {
      method
        .call(this, params)
        .then(function(result) {
          cb.call(this, result);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          eb.call(this, eb);
        })
        .finally(function() {
          this.spinCount--;
        });
    }, 0);
  }
```

And the spinner, of course, would be:

```
<lightning-spinner if:true={spinCount}></lightning-spinner>
```

While this is technically complicated, we've been told to do this logic ourselves for a while now, because aura:waiting and aura:doneWaiting can be called multiple times in unpredictable order, so maintaining control ourselves is the best option.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, thanks for your answer. However could you advise how do we link the callServer method to the server-side call because I guess this is a custom-made method? Moreover would you please advise about cb and eb parameters as well? Thanks!

Comment: @Minh In your JavaScript, you'd call it as `this.callServer(apexFunction, this.handleResult, this.handleError)`, where `apexFunction` is the imported function name, `this.handleResult` is a method to handle the Promise resolved state, and `this.handleError` can display an error or otherwise handle the error (you may need multiple functions).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice.